# Can more than one Web Services be called at the same time from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have made a social networking application and I m calling various Web Servies to get the Users's different data like the Friend list, the latest updates etc.

But while I m calling one Web Service in background, and then make call to another, the first one stops, no response comes back for the first one...

What should be done for that?

Is it not possible to call two Web Services at a time??

Comment: pls provide more info. like some code, so that we can help u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are calling services. If you will show your code, any one can help you more...

you can try this -

```
    - (NSData *)fetchProfileData:(NSString *)accessToken{
          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverURL];
          request= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
          [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
          NSError *error;
          NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
          NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&error];
         return responseData;
    }
```

to call other web services create separate separate functions for each service like

```
    - (NSData *)fetchFriendsList:(NSString *)accessToken{
       //write your logic, you see above method for more details 
    } 

    - (NSData *)fetchUpdates:(NSString *)accessToken{
       //write your logic, you see above method for more details
    }
```

call above methods from your view controllers like

```
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callFetchProfileDataServices:) toTarget:self withObject:@"userToken"];

    -(void)callFetchProfileDataServices:(NSString*)token{
        NSData *response = [self fetchProfileData:token];
        //now parse response data data using suitable parser 
    }
```

You need to create separate separate threads for each services and you may save these data in member field also .

Comment: I already created separate functions for each web-service, but yeah the NSThread concept worked for me... Thanks @mithilesh